# How do I give a position for each block in an instanedMesh (three.js)?

Tags: three.js, voxel

I am making a 3d voxel game using threejs. I am coming across a problem where I have a geometry, as well as a material and I am trying to make an instanced mesh of about 1000 blocks (to increase game performance) and I want to give each of those blocks a different position. How do I do this? This is what I have so far so you can refer to it, thanks!

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(1, 1, 1);
var blockMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color : 0x00ff00});
```

Now that I have this, what should I continue to write if I want about 1000 blocks in an instancedMesh in certain positions that I want? Thanks again :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially [`How do I ask a good question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [`How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Regarding your question, [take a look at this example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=instanc#webgl_instancing_dynamic) and its [code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_instancing_dynamic.html). It uses `InsteancedMesh` to set the position/rotation of each instance (with `setMatrixAt`) in each frame.